# What is wrong with this json.load?

Tags: python, json, file, load

I have this code in python 3

```
import json
with open('calldb.json', 'r') as G:
    data = json.load(G)
    print(data)
```

and this json file

```
[
   {
     "n": {
       "identity": 0,
       "labels": [
         "Service",
         "Test"
       ],
       "properties": {
         "name": "Service1",
         "uid": "XD2020",
         "state": "new",
         "type": "internetDualhome"
       }
     }
   },
   {
     "n": {
       "identity": 1,
       "labels": [
         "Test",
         "intpe"
       ],
       "properties": {
         "name": "Pe1",
         "ip": "172.20.20.1/32"
--------skipped lines-----------
```

**those omitted lines are for not sharing the entire file**

when i run the program i get this error

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

what is the problem with this json?

Comment: Your JSON cuts off and it says "skipped lines". It certainly won't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Skipped lines? If you did not add that line, your file is not formatted to be valid JSON.

If you added that line, I would recommend checking your JSON file against a JSON schema. Its possible you do not have a proper bracket or curl in the right spot.

I have used this [JSON schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) in the past and find their syntax to be quite helpful. If you are not sure what version of the schema to select in the drop-down, I recommend defaulting to Draft v4

Comment: no, those lines omitted are not to hit all the json

Comment: @Alan I have added a link to a validator which has helped me in the past. Give this a try and let us know of your results!